# Getting jinja2 tag and html text on same line

Tags: html, text, formatting, jinja2

I have HTML code like this:

```
<h3>
    "Thank you {{form.name}}!"
</h3>
```

I am getting "Thank you" with CSS retained on one line and the jinja2 element on the next line printed in white space. How can I print both of them on the same line without losing original CSS formatting. Thanks in advance. --regards vishwa.

Comment: There is an unclosed quotation mark in the snippet you've shared. Is it a typo?

Comment: thanks for pointing the typo vahdet. if you know the solution for this let me know. i have to debug my code. There might be something wrong in my html and views.py.

Comment: Well, you did not share your views.py or so. I could just tried to reproduce your issue on a [playground](http://jinja.quantprogramming.com/); but it works.

Comment: vahdet the playground link is not working. I might have caught my own bug. Using {{form.name}} is actually putting form element in my html page. I have to use SQL within my template HTML page to get the name. Will update once I try that.